# Android Transform3d Hides Text (z axis positioning)

Tags: android, css

I have been scouring the internet looking for a solution, but none as been found.

When I move an elements Z position the text in the element disappears. It works in all other browsers and devices, except for Android.

Please, let me know if there is a solution or a work-around.

CSS:

```
-webkit-transform:perspective(800px) translate3d(10px,10px,100px);
   -moz-transform:perspective(800px) translate3d(10px,10px,100px);
     -o-transform:perspective(800px) translate3d(10px,10px,100px);
        transform:perspective(800px) translate3d(10px,10px,100px);
```